# How to use leaveEvent with listView created from QtCreator form?

Tags: qt, event-handling, signals, qt-creator, slot

I am trying to call some function (or slot) when the mouse leaves the space of my `QListView` (`tableView`). Normally, you could use the `leaveEvent()` function. So for example I could write

```
void MainWindow::leaveEvent(QEvent * event){
    qApp->quit();
}
```

This works as intended. When the mouse leaves the `MainWindow` widget, the application quits. However, what if I wanted to quit the application when the mouse leaves my `QListView` object which is INSIDE of my `MainWindow` widget?

How do I reimplement a function for this `QListView` when it was created within Qt Creator's form designer?

Here is what I have (unsuccessfully) tried:

```
void Ui::tableView::leaveEvent(){
    qApp->quit();
}
```

And below, I have tried using `leaveEvent()` as a signal, and it says `leaveEvent` is undefined (can you even use events as `SIGNAL`s?)

```
connect(ui->tableView, SIGNAL(leaveEvent(QEvent *event)), this, SLOT(testSlot()));
```

Basically, I am trying to call some function when the mouse leaves my `tableView` which was created with Qt Creator's form designer. The `QListView` class seems to have a `mouseEntered()` `SIGNAL`, but not `mouseLeave()` `SIGNAL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass QListView and reimplement the leaveEvent (example):

```
class MyListView : public QListView
{
     Q_OBJECT

    void MyListView::leaveEvent(QEvent *e){
        QListView::leaveEvent(e);
        anyOtherAction();
    }
}
```